# Jquerymobile themeroller doesnt color submit button, its stays gray

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem that i just can't seem to fix, the problem is that for my contact page i have a submit button like most contact forms do :) that is not the problem... the problem is that i can't seem to style my submit button, now i am not a total dummie and i have tried almost all the solutions i could make sense of

http://yellowgreenmedia.info/test-themes/Contact.php

Is there someone who can point me into the right direction... any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Dave

Comment: You have it set to data-theme="c" when the rest of your elements are using data-theme="a". Add data-theme="a" to the input/submit button

Comment: Thank you Phill, that was it adding the data-theme="a" did the trick
You have no idea how much you have helped me here :-))

Answer (score 0):

You have the Submit button theme set to use theme-c, change it to use theme-a. More on Button Themes:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html

You have:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">
```

Change to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" data-theme="a">
```